# Limit on multiple table union

Tags: mysql

I've this mysql query with a limit on each select, but I want a limit of 1 on the complete query too. I've tried to build a Select around the whole query too, but it still goes through all the tables, even if there's a result in the first one so the duration is the same. I want the query to stop as soon as it gets a result. Is there any solution for this?

```
(SELECT count(*) FROM table1 i JOIN table1item it where it.columnId = 2 LIMIT 1)union
(SELECT count(*) FROM table2 i JOIN table2item it where it.columnId = 2 LIMIT 1)union
(SELECT count(*) FROM table3 i JOIN table3item it where it.columnId = 2 LIMIT 1)union
(SELECT count(*) FROM table4 i JOIN table4item it where it.columnId = 2 LIMIT 1)union
(SELECT count(*) FROM table5 i JOIN table5item it where it.columnId = 2 LIMIT 1)union
(SELECT count(*) FROM table6 i JOIN table6item it where it.columnId = 2 LIMIT 1)union
(SELECT count(*) FROM table7 i JOIN table7item it where it.columnId = 2 LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: You want to union 7 tables with max of 1 value each and then end up with 1 value at the end? Show your query with the whole thing wrapped in an outer select. That's what you need to do if Im understanding your request.

Comment: I only want to check if the 2 exists in one of the colums in the 7 tables. So 1 result total would be enough. I'm just searching for the quickest way to figure that out. So as soon as the query finds a result in one of the tables it should stop and give me the result back.

Comment: Little suggestion, you dont need to add LIMIT 1 in each sub-select, if you're doing COUNT() without GROUP BY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workmate found a solution which really reduces the query time (0.25 instead of 0.75 in my test case):

```
SELECT 
                case 
                               when count(*) > 0 
                                               then 1                                                  
                else (
    SELECT 
                case 
                               when count(*) > 0 
                                               then 1                                                  
                else (
    SELECT 
                case 
                               when count(*) > 0 
                                               then 1                                                  
                else (
    SELECT 
                case 
                               when count(*) > 0 
                                               then 1                                                  
                else (
    SELECT 
                case 
                               when count(*) > 0 
                                               then 1                                                  
                else (
    SELECT 
                case 
                               when count(*) > 0 
                                               then 1                                                  
                else (
    SELECT 
                case 
                               when count(*) > 0 
                                               then 1                                                  
                else 0
end as result
FROM table1 i JOIN table1item it where it.fooId = 1 LIMIT 1 
    )
end as result
FROM table2 i JOIN table2item it where it.fooId = 1 LIMIT 1 
    )
end as result
FROM table3 i JOIN table3item it where it.fooId = 1 LIMIT 1 
    )
end as result
FROM table4 i JOIN table4item it where it.fooId = 1 LIMIT 1 
    )
end as result
FROM table5 i JOIN table5item it where it.fooId = 1 LIMIT 1 
    )
end as result
FROM table6 i JOIN table6item it where it.fooId = 1 LIMIT 1 
    )
end as result
FROM table7 i JOIN table7item it where it.fooId = 1 LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Add UNION ALL to be sure you'll get results from all table if they are equal.

```
(SELECT count(*) FROM table1 i JOIN table1item it where it.columnId = 2) UNION ALL
(SELECT count(*) FROM table2 i JOIN table2item it where it.columnId = 2) UNION ALL
(SELECT count(*) FROM table3 i JOIN table3item it where it.columnId = 2) UNION ALL
(SELECT count(*) FROM table4 i JOIN table4item it where it.columnId = 2) UNION ALL
(SELECT count(*) FROM table5 i JOIN table5item it where it.columnId = 2) UNION ALL
(SELECT count(*) FROM table6 i JOIN table6item it where it.columnId = 2) UNION ALL
(SELECT count(*) FROM table7 i JOIN table7item it where it.columnId = 2)
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it still didn't reduce the query time if there's already a result in the first table.